# How to run wget cron command on elastic beanstalk config

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have one instance on elastic Beanstalk.
According to the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/) for running the cron on beanstalk environment I would create a file named something like "`mycron.config`" and place it in the .ebextensions folder.

I've done that.
The "`mycron.config`" file read like this:

```
commands:
     command: "*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null https://example.com/pull-shopify-orders"
```

I'm attempting to hit this url every 5 minutes.
The cron isn't running.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what documentation you are referring to (no link), but I guess you write about `cron.yaml` which is only for worker environments.

To setup `cron` on web environments,  you have to create `/etc/cron.d/mycron` "manually" with proper content and permissions.

This procedure is explained in a very recent AWS blog post:

- [How do I create cron jobs on Amazon EC2 instances in Elastic Beanstalk environments?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/)

The blog creates `cron-linux.config` with the exemplary content of (modified content for your use-case):

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            */5 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh

    "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            #date > /tmp/date
            /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null https://example.com/pull-shopify-orders
            exit 0

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/mycron.bak"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer yes that's the one I was referring to.  That's the one I was looking at but I'm asking how would i setup a wget to access an external link? @Marcin would I insert this "*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null https://example.com/pull-shopify-orders" in #Your actual script content?

Comment: @FabricioG I modified the example to match your use-case closer.

Comment: You're awesome Marcin THANK YOU! @Marcin